# Comparing 2 columns on 2 pandas dataframes for equality

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes pd and pd2:

pd

```
Name A B
t1   3 4
t5   2 2
fry  4 5
net  3 3
```

pd2

```
Name A B
t1   3 4
t5   2 2
fry  4 5
net  3 3
```

I want to make sure that the columns 'Name' between the two dataframes match not only the names (t1,t5,etc..) but also they need to be in the same order.  I've tried `chekS = (df.index == df2.index).all(axis=1).astype(str)`  with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Name` is your index, you either change your axis to 0, or use `chekS = sum(df.index != df2.index)`. If it's not the index, then `chekS = sum(df.Name != df2.Name)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

If Name is the column not the index as your sample dataframe suggests, you can compare the two columns

```
(df1['Name'] == df2['Name']).all()
```

It returns True in this case.

Lets say your df2 is

```
    Name    A   B
0   t1      3   4
1   t5      2   2
2   net     3   3
3   fry     4   5
```

I just flipped the rows at index 2 and 3 keeping the values same,

```
(df1['Name'] == df2['Name']).all()
```

will return False